# Ajax request redirect

Tags: ajax, perl, http

I am doing a Ajax request, in the response depending on some condition. I might send a 301 status code with a location(redirect) URL. But when I do that there is a ajax request to the redirect URL, but I want it to be a normal request not a ajax request.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can't see the redirect response, only the final response from the URL the browser was redirected to.
Javascript can try to recognize the situation by analyzing the response content: Maybe it expects JSON but gets HTML (e.g. a login page :-) )

To do it right you'd need to modify the service to return a non-redirect response code to the Javascript which it can then handle (e.g. 401 when the session expires and the user must log in again)

Comment: I can't do this. I can only do it on server side.

Answer (score 1):

it's pretty easy, you might want the server to return an url instead of performing redirection, end then use `window.location` to perform redirection in javascript :).

Comment: I can't do this. I can only do it on server side.

Comment: So you'd like the server response from an uncooperative AJAX request to trigger a page refresh without making any client side change? I hope you can't do that.

Comment: @MojoUser I strongly believe it is not possible.